# Where does Haskell keep its libraries?

Tags: haskell, module, libraries

Let's say I start off with

```
import Network 
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import Data.Binary
```

I'm using GHC (version 7.6.3), and haven't strayed much from the default configuration.  Where can I find the function definitions for these three modules?  (I don't want to make a habit of consulting Hoogle when the code is on my computer)

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304714/seeing-typeclass-definition-in-ghci-for-a-specific-type

Comment: I'm closing the question as duplicate then. Comment here if you have any objections or if something in that answer isn't clear.