# How to find instance implementation of an operator in ghci

Tags: haskell

I know about :t and :info, but let's say for [] I want to see the definition of instance definition of >>= for type class Monad, whats' the quickest way to do that in ghci? Or is there some standard tool?

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. The best thing is to use `:info`. It also tells you in which module the instances are defined. you can then search for the module on hoogle or similar and see the source code.

Comment: I think you can use lambdabot and call it from inside ghci, but I don't know how active it's developed these days. So during installation not everything might be smooth

Comment: No. This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304714/seeing-typeclass-definition-in-ghci-for-a-specific-type

Comment: this is the single most important feature that is missing.